# Equation number not on the extreme right?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, numbering

I am trying to number the equation in my thesis. All of the equation numbers are being displayed correctly on the extreme right (of the text area). However, in one equation, I am facing a little problem. The equation number in this case is stick to the equation and is looking quite annoying in my thesis. The code of the equation is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
{\mu ^'}\left( {{x_{mn}}} \right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 2{\left( {{\mu _{mn}}} \right)^2},0 \le {\mu _{mn}} < 0.5 \\ 
 1 - 2{\left( {1 - {\mu _{mn}}} \right)^2},0.5 \le {\mu _{mn}} \le 1 \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Please help me to display the equation number on the extreme right.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I made a rollback since with the edit, there was no problem anymore. Please don't fix such errors in the code in _questions!_ (And please don't approve such edits.) Or shall we discuss this on Meta?

Comment: @HendrikVogt I agree, questions shouldn’t be answered by editing them. Though, in this case I approved since the wrong syntax made the MWE not even compilable. I wonder how one got an—albeit faulty–output?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Hit enter often enough, or even better, hit `q` and enter!

Comment: Ok. I shouldn't have corrected the \mu^' in the original post. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, use `\mu'`, not `\mu^'`, or you will get an error. Once this modification has been made, the equation number appears as far to the right as possible, given the current geometry:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
{\mu'}\left( {{x_{mn}}} \right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 2{\left( {{\mu _{mn}}} \right)^2},0 \le {\mu _{mn}} < 0.5 \\ 
 1 - 2{\left( {1 - {\mu _{mn}}} \right)^2},0.5 \le {\mu _{mn}} \le 1 \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note it's more common (and equivalent) to use `\mu'` rather than `\mu^\prime`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok. I'll modify my solution accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your code actually compile without errors: `{\mu ^'}` -> `\mu'`, then I have no problems. In math mode, `'` is equivalent to `^{\prime}`.